# Как использовать "конкатенацию" строк в datagridview?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.Помогите написать код который будет добавлять к тексту в поле 1 ，дополнительный текст через запятую.(или значение)
К примеру так:

```
№     Id   Name
1     545  Test1
2     400  Test2
```

Как к примеру дописать 545 еще одно значение через запятую(взятое из массива).
Цикл for абсолютно не к чему

```
int [] array = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,5,5,3,423,43,65,5,3,2};
Random s = new Random();

void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
    {
        int rand = s.Next(0,10);
        for(int k=0;k<rand;k++)
        {
            Data_test_grid.Rows.Add(i,array[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Нашел где то код с String.Join но он так же не работает...
Уже второй день бью голову，не могу понять как это решить.Прошу помочь.

Comment: Доп. текст должен быть отдельной колонкой, но под единым заголовком (id), т.е. colspan нужен? Если да, то в стандартном гриде его нет. А если необходимо модифицировать существующую колонку, то в чем проблема? Указываете Data_test_grid.Rows.Add(i,array[k] + "," + <нужное число>);

Comment: Вот по ссылке все видно.http://s019.radikal.ru/i636/1609/42/8968a2156d5f.png числа которые одинаковые в №，в id должны быть связаны через запятую вот так: http://s018.radikal.ru/i516/1609/56/97d9ae613cfb.png

Comment: Судя по картинкам, вам нужно сгруппировать данные. Но непонятно, что должно произойти с `Name`.

Comment: А ну скажу так:Как вы видите по названию второго столбца，это id.У каждого Id есть свое название...Но это уже другая история.Name можно вовсе "вычеркнуть".Но давайте просто поясню что это за программа.Программа пишется для чтения одного из бинарных файлов одной игры...Поэтому у каждого ID есть свое имя，но оно берется уже с другого файла..

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, имеется класс:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Имеется набор данных:

```
var tests = new List<Test>
{
    new Test { Num=1, Id=38210, Name="Test1" },
    new Test { Num=1, Id=38210, Name="Test1" },
    new Test { Num=1, Id=38210, Name="Test1" },
    new Test { Num=2, Id=4343, Name="Test2" },
    new Test { Num=3, Id=348211, Name="Test3" },
    new Test { Num=3, Id=348211, Name="Test3" }
};
```

Группируем данные по `Num`:

```
var grouped = tests.GroupBy(t => t.Num)
    .Select(g => new { Num = g.Key, Id = string.Join(",", g.Select(t => t.Id)) })
    .ToList();
```

Привязываем сгруппированные значения к датагриду:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = grouped;
```

Comment: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy' and no extension method 'GroupBy' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)Id в int32...GroupBy похоже не принимает его

Comment: @ლუკაბერიანიძე - Я применяю `GroupBy` к `List<T>`, а не к `int`. Просто правильно скопируйте код!

Comment: Как бы не делал，результат выполнения программы такой:Появляются строки，но они пустые.